# Determining if a level exists

Tags: c#, linq, wpf

This is the code that I'm using. I'm working on LINQ TO SQL and I'm using this model in my program:

[How can I model this class in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072819/how-can-i-model-this-class-in-a-database/7072841#7072841)

The person must have to enter the level, for example 1.2, 1.1.4, etc. The program must check if  the level is available or busy. The function `ToIntArray` is an extension and consists of splitting the text and converting the resulting `string[]` to `int[]`.

The first condition, as you can see, is an inconsistency which I have in this post:

[Problems with nullable types in a LINQ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085713/problems-with-nullable-types-in-a-linq-function)

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NorthwindDataContext cd = new NorthwindDataContext();

    int[] levels = LevelTextBox.Text.ToIntArray('.');
    string newGroupName = NameTextBox.Text;

    Objective currentObjective = null;
    int? identity = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < levels.Length - 1; i++ )
    {
        int currentRank = levels[i];

        if (identity == null)
        {
            currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                                where p.Level == currentRank && p.Parent_ObjectiveID == null
                                select p).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            currentObjective = (from p in cd.Objective
                                where p.Level == currentRank && p.Parent_ObjectiveID == identity
                                select p).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        if (currentObjective == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Levels don't exist");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            identity = currentObjective.ObjectiveID;
        }
    }

    if (currentObjective != null)
    {
        if (levels.Last() == currentObjective.Level)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Level already exists");
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var aux = (from p in cd.Objective
                   where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == null && p.Level == levels.Last()
                   select p).SingleOrDefault();

        if (aux != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Level already exists");
            return;
        }
    }

    var newObjective = new Objective();
    newObjective.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
    newObjective.Level = levels.Last();
    newObjective.Parent_ObjectiveID = currentObjective == null ? null : (int?)currentObjective.ObjectiveID ;

    cd.Objective.InsertOnSubmit(newObjective);
    cd.SubmitChanges();

    MessageBox.Show("The new objective has added successfully");
    NameTextBox.Clear();
    LoadObjectives();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few  comments:

1. You should move this code from the `AddButton_Click` to some business logic class.
2. Maybe you should add some validation of `LevelTextBox.Text`, before using its value.
3. You should split this code into different methods.

   > You have three responsibilities here:
   >
   > 1. Find out  if the level exists at all.
   > 2. Find out if the specified level already exists.
   > 3. Create a new level.
   >
   > The fact that all three actions use the same data doesn't mean you need to put them in one method.
4. Maybe I get it wrong somewhere, but I can't understand how this code checks if the level already exists. I can't see how the code will ever get into the `MessageBox.Show("Level already exists");` in both places.